# how to get previous values of switch on click of switch?

Tags: android

I want to know the value of pervious state of switch on click ,like example switch is already on and when i click i need to get the value as the switch is on and viscera when switch is off .How to get this in android?

Comment: Since it is a boolean value, isn't that always just the opposite of what you're are reading from the current value?

Comment: Hi please provide some more info because it's not cleared

Comment: so we cannot get pervious state values on click of switch?

Answer (score 0):

you have the current value, it is boolean so the old value is the opposite of the current value...

```
 sButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
  @Override
  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton cb, boolean on){
   if(on) tView.setText("Switch was off.....");
   else tView.setText("Switch was on.....");
  }
 });
```